# sending an auto mail from excel based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, email, multiple-conditions

I am a VBA novice so thanks in advance for anyone who can help me here. Basically I am using an adapted Ron de Bruin piece of code to automatically send a mail to students when their attendance drops below a certain level as displayed in a particlular excel cell. So far, so good, the Ron de Bruin stuff looks after this. 
But there is another criterion which I want to add and that is basically to only send the mail if there is also a letter 'Y' in a different cell in the same row as the attendance. 
To summarize, I only want the mail to go to people who fulfill the two criteria, 1)dropping below a certain level, and 2)having a 'Y' in another cell, but the code at the moment only accounts for the first criterion. Huge thanks. Alun (code below)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()


Dim FormulaRange As Range
Dim NotSentMsg As String
Dim MyMsg As String
Dim SentMsg As String
Dim MyLimit As Double



NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
MyLimit = 80

'Set the range with Formulas that you want to check
Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("BH279:BH280")

On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
        If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
            MyMsg = "Not numeric"
        Else
            If .Value < MyLimit Then


                MyMsg = SentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    Call Mail_with_outlook2
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
         & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: You could fix your formula with an `IF(AAA111="Y",percentage,1)` preamble. If you'd like to improve your knowledge and not just fix this problem, I'd recommend the `homework` tag (not sure of the spelling).

Comment: Thanks so much Richard, I'll try this out Monday and let you know. If you ever run for public office you can be assured of my support!

Comment: Richard thanks, im trying the answer below first because my knowledge is so limited that im not sure how to use your suggestion, where to paste the IF(AAA111="Y",percentage,1) and what i would need to add for it to work. if you could elaborate, i would be eternally grateful. Alun

Comment: I got the alternative method working so you dont have to waste time explaining anything to me. really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If .Value2 < MyLimit And Not .EntireRow.Find(What:="Y", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Call Mail_with_outlook2
'If you look for the complementer solution, remove the " Not"
```

You look for the value `"Y"` in the same row.
I'd recommend setting output variables as well to the mailing macro `Call Mail_with_outlook2(emailaddress, name, title, MyValue)`.

Comment: Hi user3819867, thanks a mil for this. I gotta wait til Monday to try it but I'm sure it'll work. I'll let you know. Thanks so much. Have a great weekend.

Comment: Hi again, 
I pasted your code in in place of

If .Value < MyLimit Then
but got error message (nesting i think)
So then I put your code in below the original line, but still the mail was sending regardless of whether there was a “Y” or an ”A” or whatever in the other cell (Column G, in this case).

I have no idea of the syntax, but I had envisioned a line like (I’ll write it in English!):

If .Value < MyLimit AND Cell G of the corresponding row contains a “Y” Then 

send mail


Forgive my ignorance, and thousand thank yous for your patience!

Alun

Comment: My syntax just puts the `Call` iteration in the same line. I believe that might cause your problems. `If .Value2 < MyLimit And Not .EntireRow.Find(What:="Y", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then` is the way for you. Place it in lieu of the original `If ... Then`.

Comment: this works perfectly. i dont know how to thank you. thanks so much!

Comment: There's one things you can do for me, which is marking my answer as correct. The other thing I expect you to do for yourself is understand what I did and keep learning!

Comment: Ja I ticked the tick and its green now. And I'm gonna keep on the VBA road. Cheers